# what is the best ways to save the information of the lines as a replacement for using line.all

Tags: pine-script

I am wondering  what would the best way of saving the information of the drawn lines (ie, instead of using `line.all`).
The problem with `line.all` is that it gives all the lines, but I only want to save the information for some specific lines that I drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `var array.new_line`. Push whatever line you want to store and delete when you don't need them.

It has to be `var` so that the array will keep its value on the next executions.

You can initialize it as:

```
var line_container = array.new_line()
```

or if you know its size beforehand, you can do:

```
var line_container = array.new_line(SIZE)
```

Comment: Thanks, at the very first how should I initialize it though?
`var array.new_line line_container = ??`